# What is "のほうだろう" here?

Tags: sentence, reading-comprehension

[image]

So the old woman explains that in place of her dead husband her kid has been helping. Then she says the kid won't settle into a home much but

[image]

I assume この時節 in "these occasions" but how does なほうだろうと here actually work? I take something is being omitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 親孝行 is a na-adjective that means "kind and caring towards one's parents".
- (～な)方 ("～'s side") is used to add a nuance of choosing one from two. This person is saying that, if she has to judge whether her son is 親孝行 or not, she would choose to say that he is 親孝行.
- The implied subject of 親孝行な方だ is her son, and 思う is omitted after と.

> この時節、(息子は)親孝行**な方**だろうと(思う)。
>
> By today's standards, (my son) is **relatively** a filial person, I think.

Similar examples of 方:

- こんなのまだ簡単な方ですよ。
  This is still relatively easy.
- あなたはまだいいほうだ。
  You're still a lucky one.